# C# WPF WinForms dataGridView overlap with StatusBar when resizing window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, overlap

In a C# WPF project, I imported WinForms dataGridView instead of WPF dataGrid for some reasons.
The problem is, When I resizing windows, dataGridView overlaps with StatusBar (maybe any other controls) located in the last row of the Grid. I want dataGridView in TabItem1 to do not overlap with other controls as TabItem 2.

```
<TabItem Header="Item 1">
    <WindowsFormsHost Name="wf_dataGrid3" Background="LightGray" Height="126">
        <wf:DataGridView x:Name="dataGridView3" BackgroundColor="LightGray" BorderStyle="Fixed3D">
        </wf:DataGridView>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Item 2">
    <Label Content="Test" MinHeight="126" Background="LightGray"/>
</TabItem>
```

I already tried with Panel.ZIndex="1000" and ClipToBounds="True", but both are not working.

Is it impossible to bound WinForms' dataGridView in WPF project?

Comment: Can  you explain what is the reason you're using winforms `DataGridView` in wpf? This seems to be the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Comment: WPF uses *composition* (complicated technique to avoid constant redrawing), while winforms doesn't. This could be the reason, wpf can't draw winforms control properly. Your  *real* problem is a choice to use winforms control in wpf.

Comment: Wow, I never expected such a quick answer! First of all, thanks all for your quick answers. It seems impossible. I'm pretty new in WPF and not familiar with WPF's dataGrid. The reason why I used WinForms DGV is that I don't know how to fiil each dataGrid cell when button click.  (as you know, this is pretty easy in WinForms' DGV). Actually, I checked about binding, but I couldn't get it.

Comment: Tell me your window size or grid size @Caliboy

Comment: Window size: Height="800" Width="1400" WindowState="Maximized"

<RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="700*"></RowDefinition>
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

In the 3rd row of the Grid, 4 tabs whose Height="126" are located, and all the first TabItem has DGV. The application starts at Full screen, but when I resize windows, any DGV overlaps with the status bar which is in the 4th row of the Grid.